# Building a custom component with MenuItem of Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

*We are using react with typescript.*

I'm currently wrapping most of the MUI components for flexibility.
We actually hit a problem with **MenuItem**, the first error that occur was this :
*"Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?"*.

My component was a **Function Component** so i did switch to a **ForwardRefRenderFunction**. However, i was unable to make it work.

Here is my render function :

```
interface IDMSMenuItemProps extends MenuItemProps<"li", { button?: true }> {}

const DMSMenuItem: React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLButtonElement, IDMSMenuItemProps> = (props, ref) => {
  return (
      <MenuItem ref={ref} {...props}></MenuItem>
  );
};

export default DMSMenuItem;
```

This render function result with a compilation error :

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type '((instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<HTMLButtonElement | null> | null' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLLIElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLLIElement> | null | undefined'.
      Type '(instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLLIElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLLIElement> | null | undefined'.
        Type '(instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLLIElement | null) => void'.
```

If i use *React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<any, any>* it actually run but once i click the menu in the app i have theses two following errors :

```
The above error occurred in the <li> component:
    at li
    at ButtonBase (https://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:15025:22)
    at WithStyles(ForwardRef(ButtonBase)) (https://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:197724:31)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property current, object is not extensible
    at setRef (:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:48576)
    at :3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:48759
```

The parent component is this:

```
interface IDMSSelectProps extends SelectProps {
  hint?: string;
}
const DMSSelect: React.FunctionComponent<IDMSSelectProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <FormControl error={props.error} fullWidth={true}>
      <InputLabel>{props.label}</InputLabel>
      <Select fullWidth={true} {...props}>
        {props.children}
      </Select>
      <FormHelperText>{props.hint}</FormHelperText>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default DMSSelect;
```

The use case is :

```
<DMSSelect defaultValue="" hint="DMS TEST" label="DMS Selecto">
        <DMSMenuItem value="">Empty Value for First Option</DMSMenuItem>
</DMSSelect>
```

How can i achieve a custom component with menuitem ?

**Edit**: Still having the forward ref error even with the render function:

```
Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `ForwardRef(Menu)`.
    at DMSMenoItem
    at ul
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `innerRef` instead:

```
<MenuItem innerRef={ref} {...props}></MenuItem>
```

Comment: The compilation error is gone but now i'm left with the same error as <any,any> which is : error occurred in the <li> component:
    at li
    at ButtonBase (https://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:15025:22)
And Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property current, object is not extensible